# C#, IMAP - NO Bad state for this command

Tags: c#, imap

I have the following code that rarely returns an exception. Not always, only very rarely.

```
string tag = GetTag(); //_tag++; string.Format("xm{0:000} ", _tag);
string response = SendCommandGetResponse(tag + "UID SEARCH (UNDELETED) (SENTSINCE \"28-May-2018\")"); //basically just send it off, and get the response
if (!response.StartsWith("* SEARCH", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && !IsResponse(response, "OK")) {
    throw new Exception(response);
}
```

This returns the following:
xm005 NO Bad state for this command.

Why would this be occuring?
By the way, yes I am logging in using LOGIN USERNAME PASSWORD before attempting this.

I managed to find an email provider that this seems to ALWAYS happen with: post.cz

Is this an error with the IMAP Server and not my configuration?

Comment: serverfault.com is the kind of place to ask how Exchange server could get into a "bad state".

Comment: @HansPassant Should I remake the thread over there or is there a way to merge/xfer it over?

Comment: Did you select a folder?  Is it possible the folder got unselected?

Comment: @Max I selected a mailbox but I dont see how it would get unselected, the entire process is linear and does it all in one go. No ui.

Comment: It has to be an issue with their server

Comment: Hmm, do you check that the login and SELECT succeeded?  Are you always selecting INBOX?

Comment: @Max Yeah it never gets to the code I posted before they are checked to be succeeded. You can see what im doing here: https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail/ My version IS modified a lot, but what it sends to the imap stream is the same.

Comment: I would recommend trying [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) instead as aenetmail is pretty broken and unmaintained for several years now.